# Do a dynamic routing in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a route like this that I use to load the `function index()`

```
$route['group/(:any)/articles'] = 'Articles_controller';
```

Where the `(:any)` is referring to a string which is fetch dynamically from database.

I wanted to do a routing something like this:

`$route['group/(:any)/articles/(:any)'] = 'Articles_controller/$1/$2';`

2nd `(:any)` is referring to any **function name** that I create from the controller.

But this routing can't find my pages. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try replacing :any to .* . If that does not work see this related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130913/how-to-do-url-matching-regex-for-routing-framework

Comment: @FranciscodeCastro I'll try it out first. Thanks.

Comment: maybe i dont understand your problem properly but shouldnt it be `$route['group/(:any)/articles/(:any)'] = 'Articles_controller/$2/$1';` ?

Comment: @sintakonte Oh it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['group/(:any)/articles/(:any)'] = 'Articles_controller/function_name/$1/$2';
```

$1 and $2 are params you post or get request

Comment: I normally use this method in routing, but doing this means you have to create a route for every function you create in a controller. So I was thinking if it's possible to just create a route that can be used by every function in your specific controller.